# SVN How do I make visual studio warn me there is a newer version of a file?

Tags: visual-studio, svn, tortoisesvn

I hope this questions isn't too obvious or vague but I am problems searching for an answer as I'm not sure of terminology.

I am using TortoiseSVN with Unfuddle and Visual Studio 2010.

Previously I used Sourcegear's Fortress which worked really well for me but my new company uses SVN.

The problem I am currently having is:

If I edit a file in visual studio, then commit (Check in) the changes back to SVN and then
My colleague then goes to edit the same file (checks it out) from his visual studio it doesn't automatically update to the new version that I just checked in, so when he then goes to check in the file after he's changed it it throws a conflict error.

So my question is:
Is there a setting that will automatically make it update to the latest version when you check out a file? Or am I using it wrong?

Thanks for any help.

Bex

Comment: if you and your colleagues want to be informed everytime something's getting checked in into the SVN repo, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379238/notify-of-any-change-in-readonly-svn-repo/4391510#4391510

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't "check out" files, you should update before editing. Subversion uses a [different versioning model](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.basic.version-control-basics.html#svn.basic.vsn-models) than what you're used to.

Also make sure to use a good conflict editor when conflicts do occur. Personally I use DiffMerge configured as both diff and merge tool in AnkhSVN.

Comment: thanks.. so I am using it wrong! So The process should be - Update file.. then edit everytime? That was another question I was going to ask.. in fortress it shows when another person is doing something with a file (a little icon appears next to it) it still allows you to edit it, but at least you know. I assume this is also not something SVN will do because of the versioning model?

Comment: yeah, it doesn't communicate to the server that you're working on a file. I think most importantly because that doesn't scale. Imagine big repositories (apache for instance) keeping track of this...